# Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I made a function to sanitize my category lists. It worked perfectly but I have issues on my terminal.
My code:

onCategories Interface:

```
interface IEventSearchFilterProps {
  eventData: Record<string, any>;
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  onCategoriesChange: (categories: number[]) => void
}
```

```
useEffect(() => {

    const sanitizeCategories = () => {

      const filteredCategories = [selectedCategory, selectedLocation, selectedMonth].filter(category => {
        
        return Boolean(category)
      })

      return filteredCategories;
    }

    onCategoriesChange(sanitizeCategories())

  }, [selectedCategory, selectedLocation, selectedMonth])
```

My Terminal issue:

```
Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
 onCategoriesChange(sanitizeCategories())
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

With `sanitizeCategories` underlined.

With `sanitizeCategories` underlined.

Comment: What is it about the error messages that you don't understand?

Comment: why's the string type not assignable to type number?

Comment: Can you share your `onCategoriesChange` function?

Comment: Because strings are not numbers and numbers are not strings? Isn't that the whole point of Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for editing the question.

The error on your console is pretty clear on what is going wrong here.
Your function `sanitizeCategories` is returning an array of strings, and your function `onCategoriesChange` is waiting an array of numbers.

The easiest solution is change the type of arguments that `onCategoriesChange` is waiting, so it will be:

```js
interface IEventSearchFilterProps {
  eventData: Record<string, any>;
  onCategoriesChange: (categories: string[]) => void
}
```

If for some reason you are using `onCategoriesChange` in other place and there is waiting an array of numbers, you can expect both of them:

```
onCategoriesChange: (categories: number[] | string[]) => void
```